# Can I refresh the values of (an array of) objects as the variable they refer to changes?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a generator of simple sentences by combining data from two arrays. One array has the nouns/subjects and the other the verbs/actions.

Obviously, some nouns are singular and some plural. To make this work, I make the nouns objects (and a class), eg: `{ txt: "Jason", snglr: true }, { txt: "The kids" }`.

Then, I create a function that forms the verb according to whether the noun is singular or plural (`snglr: true` or `false`/`undefined`) and apply it as a method of the noun class.

I call the method from within the string of the verb/action, as in: `` { txt: `${curr_noun.verb("go", "goes")} to music class.`} ``

**My problem is that all the verbs get their values from the first noun used.** When I change the noun, the verbs still refer to the plural or singular form called by the first noun.

Is there a way to refresh the actions objects, so that each time their values refer to the current noun?

(Or if I'm totally missing an easier way, can you please let me know?)

Thanks. Here is the whole code:

```
        class noun {
            constructor(text, singular) {
                this.txt = text; // The subject of the sentence
                this.snglr = singular; // Whether the subject is singular (true) or plural (undefined/false)
                this.verb = function (plur, sing) { //this function is called from within the string containing the verb (see "actions" array, below)
                    if (sing == undefined) { // for regular verbs, we call it with one argument, eg. .verb("walk"), it creates "walks" by adding "s."
                        sing = plur + "s";
                    }
                    if (this.snglr) { // for irregular verbs, we call it with two arguments, eg. .verb("go", "goes")
                        return sing;
                    } else {
                        return plur;
                    }


                }
            }
        }

        var curr_noun = {};

        var nouns = [new noun("Jason", true), new noun("The kids")];

        curr_noun = nouns[0]; // We pick "Jason" as the sentence's subject.

        var actions = [
            { txt: `${curr_noun.verb("go", "goes")} to music class.`},
            { txt: `${curr_noun.verb("visit")} London.`}
        ];

        curr_action = actions[1];
        console.log(`${curr_noun.txt} ${curr_action.txt}`);

        // All good, so far.
        // My problem is that the above values of actions[0].txt and actions[1].txt are given based on Jason.
        // When I later change the curr_noun to "The kids," I still get singular verb forms.

        curr_noun = nouns[1];
        curr_action = actions[0];
        curr_noun.verb();
        console.log(`${curr_noun.txt} ${curr_action.txt}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we could simplify this code a bit. You could create a function to create the sentences. This function would take a noun object and verb object and the grammatical *object* which is a string.

This way we can remove the class and reduce the number of lines that we write. With this approach, we can also ensure the nouns and verbs match in terms of plurality. Here is an example:

```js
const nouns = [
  {
    text: 'Jason',
    isSingular: true,
  },
  {
    text: 'The kids',
    isSingular: false,
  },
];

// in grammar, the noun at the end of the sentence is called object
const verbs = [
  {
    // "to" is actually part of the verb here(prepositional verb)
    singular: 'goes to',
    plural: 'go to',
  },
  {
    singular: 'visits',
    plural: 'visit',
  },
];

// in grammar, the noun at the end of the sentence is called object
const objects = ['music class.', 'London.'];

const createSentence = (noun, verb, object) => {
  const myVerb = noun.isSingular === true ? verb.singular : verb.plural;
  return `${noun.text} ${myVerb} ${object}`;
};

console.log(createSentence(nouns[0], verbs[1], objects[1]));
console.log(createSentence(nouns[1], verbs[0], objects[0]));
```

Comment: Thanks, @jigg. It seems that I will go with a solution similar to yours. I thought that a method called from within an object property would be called every time the object is accessed and not only during its definition, but it doesn't work like this, I guess.

Comment: @user11374179 that's great to hear! Feel free to vote my answer up and mark my answer as accepted if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am not saying that this is how it should be done, but just pointing out where the problem is.

You define your `var actions` based on `curr_noun = nouns[1];`, i.e. "Jason", here:

```
var actions = [
    { txt: `${curr_noun.verb("go", "goes")} to music class.` },
    { txt: `${curr_noun.verb("visit")} London.` }
];
```

This never changes. So when referring to `actions[0]` later, they are still based on "Jason".Try to `console.log(this.txt)` inside the .verb-method to see where it goes wrong.

When reassigning them again to "The kids" before logging, it works fine:

```
curr_noun = nouns[1];

var actions = [
    { txt: `${curr_noun.verb("go", "goes")} to music class.` },
    { txt: `${curr_noun.verb("visit")} London.` }
];

curr_action = actions[0];

console.log(`${curr_noun.txt} ${curr_action.txt}`);
// -> The kids go to music class.
```

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. I followed your advice and console-logged every step. I realised that the verb method is not fired upon the formation of each sentence, but only at the start, when the var actions array is defined. Once the values are in place, they stay there, as you say. Hm. So, there is no way to make an object property refresh its value, as in my case?